# Is there a options to get output via pivot or any other options

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot

I have 2 tables: orders and product. Order table contains order_id, id(product_id), order_date, and cost.
The product table contains product_id, name, category, type, partner, commission, eff_date, and term_date.
Since the product_id is repeating in the product table I get duplicates records when joining with orders table.
My aim is to pivot the product table data so I can get 1 record for a order.

I tried pivoting the data but didn't succeed.

Orders

| Order ID | ID | Order Date | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 05-06-2023 | 11 |
| 2 | 1 | 10-11-2023 | 12 |
| 3 | 2 | 01-02-2023 | 13 |
| 4 | 3 | 08-09-2023 | 14 |
| 5 | 4 | 19-07-2023 | 15 |
| 6 | 1 | 12-31-2023 | 15 |

Products:

| Product ID | Name | Category | Type | Partner | Commission | Eff Date | Term Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | P | Primary | V1 | 0.3 | 01-01-2023 | 31-13-2023 |
| 1 | A | M | Secondary | V2 | 0.3 | 01-01-2023 | 31-13-2023 |
| 1 | A | P | Expired | V1 | 0.275 | 01-01-2022 | 31-13-2022 |
| 1 | A | P | Expired | V1 | 0.25 | 01-01-2021 | 31-13-2021 |
| 2 | B | P | Primary | G1 | 0.1 | 01-01-2023 | 31-13-2023 |
| 2 | B | P | Secondary | G2 | 0.12 | 01-01-2023 | 31-13-2023 |

Output:

| Order ID | ID | Order Date | Cost | Category 1 | Category 2 | Type 1 | Type 2 | Partner 1 | Partner 2 | Commission 1 | Commission 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 05-06-2023 | 11 | P | M | Primary | Secondary | V1 | V2 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 1 | 10-11-2023 | 12 | P | M | Primary | Secondary | V1 | V2 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| 3 | 2 | 01-02-2023 | 13 | P | P | Primary | Secondary | G1 | G2 | 0.1 | 0.12 |
| 4 | 2 | 08-09-2023 | 14 | P | P | Primary | Secondary | G1 | G2 | 0.1 | 0.12 |

```
SELECT O.orderid,
   O.id,
   O.orderdate,
   O.cost,
   P1.category   AS Category1,
   P2.category   AS Category2,
   P1.type       AS Type1,
   P2.type       AS Type2,
   P1.partner    AS Partner1,
   P2.partner    AS Partner2,
   P1.commission AS Commission1,
   P2.commission AS Commission2
FROM   orders O
   JOIN products P1
     ON O.id = P1.productid
   JOIN products P2
     ON O.id = P2.productid
WHERE  ( O.orderdate >= p1.[effdate]
     AND O.orderdate <= p1.[termdate] )
    OR ( O.orderdate >= p2.[effdate]
         AND O.orderdate <= p2.[termdate] )
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: This just looks like 2 `JOIN`s where the `ON` also filters on the `[Type]`.

Comment: Please post what you have tried and the data table definition so we can best assist you here.  You might also format the sample output as a table to make it more visual

Comment: I have removed the images and added the sample input and output

Comment: I think @ThomA's idea is very good for these kind of queries, just join your product table twice to find out the different types.

Comment: @ThomA 
I tired the join however, I am still getting dups for few records my conditions might be causing the duplication. 

Where ((p1.[Type]='Primary' AND  p2.[Type]='Secondary') OR (p1.[Type]='Primary' AND  p2.[Type]='Primary'))
and [order_date]>=p1.[EffDate] and [order_date]<=p1.[TermDate]
and [order_date]>=p2.[EffDate] and [order_date]<=p2.[TermDate]

Comment: *"where the **`ON`** also filters on the `[Type]`"* that's not in the `ON`...

Comment: @ThomA: Thanks for guiding me. I was able to get the desired output via the hint. Thanks for the push :)